# MEF: Composition rejection when compose ExportFactory<T> for generic type Bar<Foo>

Tags: mef

Please see code below: method Test runs twice, once with type argument Foo and second with type argument

```
<Bar<Foo>>
```

Inside Test method we retrieve exported value for T and ExportFactory for the same type.
First invocation pass OK.
The second invocation results in composition rejection below in comments.Please note, on the second invocation the first alert pass ok, the instance was created. It is the creation of the ExportFactory for this type fails...

```
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting;
using System.Diagnostics;
namespace MefExportFactoryBug
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var tc = new TypeCatalog(new []{typeof(Foo),typeof(Bar<>),typeof(ExportFactoryProvider<>)});
            var cc = new CompositionContainer(tc, true);
            Test<Foo>(cc);//Pass OK
            Test<Bar<Foo>>(cc);// Exception below thrown
            /*
             A first chance exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Composition.ImportCardinalityMismatchException' occurred in System.ComponentModel.Composition.dll
            A first chance exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Composition.ImportCardinalityMismatchException' occurred in System.ComponentModel.Composition.dll
            A first chance exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Composition.ChangeRejectedException' occurred in System.ComponentModel.Composition.dll
            System.ComponentModel.Composition Warning: 1 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'MefExportFactoryBug.ExportFactoryProvider(MefExportFactoryBug.Bar(MefExportFactoryBug.Foo))' has been rejected. The composition remains unchanged. The changes were rejected because of the following error(s): The composition produced a single composition error. The root cause is provided below. Review the CompositionException.Errors property for more detailed information.

            1) No exports were found that match the constraint: 
                ExportFactory of: 
                ContractName    MefExportFactoryBug.Bar(MefExportFactoryBug.Foo)
                RequiredTypeIdentity    MefExportFactoryBug.Bar(MefExportFactoryBug.Foo)
                RequiredCreationPolicy    NonShared

            Resulting in: Cannot set import 'MefExportFactoryBug.ExportFactoryProvider(MefExportFactoryBug.Bar(MefExportFactoryBug.Foo)).Factory (ContractName="System.ComponentModel.Composition.Contracts.ExportFactory")' on part 'MefExportFactoryBug.ExportFactoryProvider(MefExportFactoryBug.Bar(MefExportFactoryBug.Foo))'.
            Element: MefExportFactoryBug.ExportFactoryProvider(MefExportFactoryBug.Bar(MefExportFactoryBug.Foo)).Factory (ContractName="System.ComponentModel.Composition.Contracts.ExportFactory") --> MefExportFactoryBug.ExportFactoryProvider({0}) --> TypeCatalog (Types='MefExportFactoryBug.Foo, MefExportFactoryBug.Bar({0}), ...').

             */
        }

        private static void Test<T1>(ExportProvider cc) where T1:class
        {
            var ev = cc.GetExportedValue<T1>();
            Debug.Assert(ev != null);
            var ef = cc.GetExportedValue<ExportFactoryProvider<T1>>().Factory;
            Debug.Assert(ef != null);
        }
    }
    [Export]
    public class ExportFactoryProvider<T>
    {
        [Import]
        public ExportFactory<T> Factory { get; set; }

    }

    [Export]
    public class Foo
    {
    }

    [Export]
    public class Bar<T>
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround: using SatisfyImportOnce inside ExportFactoryProvider resolves the issue and ExportFactory got created. See code below. Still not sure why export is there but ExportFactory is not in the original question's code ...

```
 using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
 using System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting;
 using System.Diagnostics;

 namespace MefExportFactoryBug
 {
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var tc = new TypeCatalog(new []{typeof(Foo),typeof(Bar<>),typeof(ExportFactoryProvider<>)});
        var cc = new CompositionContainer(tc, true);
        Test<Foo>(cc);//Pass OK
        Test<Bar<Foo>>(cc);//Pass OK now
    }

    private static void Test<T1>(CompositionContainer cc) where T1:class
    {
        var ev = cc.GetExportedValue<T1>();
        Debug.Assert(ev != null);
        var ef = new ExportFactoryProvider<T1>(cc).Factory;
        Debug.Assert(ef != null);
    }
}
[Export]
public class ExportFactoryProvider<T>
{
    public ExportFactoryProvider(ICompositionService cc)
    {
        cc.SatisfyImportsOnce(this);
    }

    [Import]
    public ExportFactory<T> Factory { get; set; }

}

[Export]
public class Foo
{
}

[Export]
public class Bar<T>
{
}
```

}